# Search for a repository in our Azure DevOps organization

Tags: azure-devops

In our azure devops organization, we have ~100 projects. Each projects holds between 1 and 20 git repositories. This makes it hard to find a specific repository unless you also remember which project it is located in.

The search box at the project list only searches by project names. Is there any way to search and find repository names?

There is a code search, but that returns results from files already *in* a repository, which gives both redundant and wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest is to call [this REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/repositories/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1).
You can call it even from the browser and use the Find feature.
Note that the *project* element is not required.

To automate, you can use a few lines of Powershell to search in the result JSON document, e.g.

```
$organization = ...
$PAT = ...a personal access token
$repoNameStart = ...initial name of repo

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("dummy:${PAT}"))
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/${organization}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=4.1" -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo" } -Credential $credential -ContentType "application/json"
$result.value | where {$_.name -like "${repoNameStart}*"}
```

(Untested code, use it as an example)

Comment: So, in other words, you can obtain all repositories by going to:
`dev.azure.com/<ORGANIZATION>/_apis/git/repositories?ap` in there you can search for the required repo. You can also bookmark this URL. Great tip!